# How to create a dataframe representing a 10000 points unit square?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, coordinates

I have to create a dataframe representing a unit square, shaped by 10 000 points. In orderd to achieve that, I need all the combinations between (coordinates) x and y, where each one goes from 0 to 1,00. The result should be something like this:

```
            x     y
  1       0,01 0,01   
  2       0,01 0,02
  n       0,12 0,04
  10000   1,00 1,00
```

I would be very glad if you can help me.

Comment: What dit you try? Why did it not work? Did you look at `expand.grid`? Might be me, but to me it's not clear how you get your desired output. Could you make a minimal example with input and expected output based on thet input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 000 points are just a 100x100 square.
Here I fix the value of y and describe the 100 values of x for this possibility.

To do this:

```
df<-data.frame(
  x = rep(seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 100), times = 100)
  y = rep(seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 100), each = 100)
)
```

Using @Heroka's suggestion, for the same output:

```
df<- expand.grid(x = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 100),
                 y = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 100)
                 )
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it is a 100x100 square.
By the way, thank you !